# SSL certificate doesn't work. Cannot connect to https://mydomain.com

Tags: ssl, lighttpd

I've setup a SSL certificate on lighttpd, on Ubuntu 10.

The issue is that when I try to access to https://mydomain.com I get "impossible to connect".
If I use http://mydomain.com, it works perfectly.

This is my configuration file:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "XXX.XXX.95.175:443" {

  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ssl.ca-file = "/var/ssl/gd_bundle.crt"
  ssl.pemfile = "/var/ssl/mydomain.com.pem"

}


$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)mydomain\.com$" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/path/to/website"
}
```

I have double checked I've done all necessary steps.

My domain correctly points to the ip XXX.XXX.95.175 (i've checked by pinging it).

Lighttpd is compiled with ssl: lighttpd-1.4.6 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver
What's wrong ?
thanks

Comment: if you're hosting on linux can you do a  "netstat -an | grep 443"? You should see a tcp port 443 open. on windows just do a netstat -an.

Comment: @Marm0t Indeed no results. I need to open port 443 I guess.. how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `$SERVER["socket"]` rather than `$HTTP["host"]`

$SERVER["socket"] does double duty for telling lighttpd what sockets to listen on as well as what to do when someone connects to it.

The SSL configuration guide [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:SSL) goes into more detail, including using $HTTP["scheme"] to tell whether the browser is using https or not (but you'll need to upgrade to at least 1.4.16... even Debian Lenny is at 1.4.19, you **really** need to upgrade)

Comment: I dunno how is possible I've copied pasted  lighttpd-1.4.6.. I've run few seconds ago and it is lighttpd-1.4.19 (ssl). So I guess it is updated. thanks